# installation problem in VLC Media player

Tags: installation

How to run media player in Ubuntu?
Is it require any plug-in or any installer package?

Need step by step help , please help me.

Answer (score 0):

just type the following in terminal:

To open terminal press the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the existing media player available in UBUNTU. Else, if you have preference for VLC, open the UBUNTU software center and search for VLC. Once located, press install. You may have to keyin your administrative password for installation to be successful. Once VLC is installed, an icon will be available in the launcher bar on the left side also. Click it, select the media you want to play and that's it.